# SAPUI5 intergration with Sharepoint REST service

Tags: sharepoint, odata, sapui5

I'm exploring ways on how to integrate Sharepoint with SAPUI5. Sharepoint will hold our data and SAPUI5 will be our frontend. I have no experience in Sharepoint development but from reading they have something they called Sharepoint REST service.I guess this REST service produces the Odata service that SAPUI5 can use.

Questions
- Is the Sharepoint REST services already built-in in Sharepoint. Meaning I don't have to do any coding to make CRUD work. 
- Since my SAPUI5 is residing on a different system (SAP system), won't integrating with Sharepoint cause any CORS issue? 
- Are there any other possible issues that I should know off for integrating SAPUI5 with Sharepoint?

Comment: CORS issues can be resolved by a reverse proxy. Just a few lines of code in Go or node.js

Comment: It is important to note that in most cases REST services don't implement the OData protocol. I don't think the Sharpoint API does provide OData. So you need to use JSONModel and call the REST API manually.

For the CORS problem, you need to configure a reverse proxy. You should be able to configure the SAP Gateway to proxy the SharePoint API.